Linear Algebra Done Right 4th Edition, Section 7C, Exercise 8
Problem
Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T$ is a positive operator if and only if the psuedoinverse $T^{\dagger}$ is a positive operator.
What I Tried
I can prove the forward direction, but I'm having trouble proving the backward direction where you first assume $T^\dagger$ is positive to prove that $T$ is positive.
I tried the following: $\forall v \in V$, $v = u + w$ where $u \in (\text{null } T)^\perp$ and $w \in \text{null }T$. Then $\langle Tv, v \rangle = \langle T(u + w), u + w\rangle = \langle Tu, T^\dagger Tu + w\rangle = \langle  Tu, T^\dagger (Tu)\rangle + \langle Tu, w\rangle$. Since $T^\dagger$ is positive, then clearly the first term is nonnegative, but don't know how to show that the second term is also nonnegative.

Show your work please, more than this

Perhaps $(T^{\dagger})^\dagger = T$?

Ah thank you @copper.hat - then it just falls back to the forward direction!
